# Studio clock: activate indicators with the keys of the numeric keypad

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the javascript code for a studio clock that I got from GitHub : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4qs4ujrip9kfr3n/AADQ8SMdHhxNigP4XoGbZvCwa?dl=0

I modified it according to my needs, however there are 3 features that I cannot code:

1. The indicator "ON AIR" can be toggled on or off with the 1 number key on the keyboard : the rectangle turns green when it is activated, and gray when it is deactivated
2. The indicator "MIC LIVE" can be toggled on or off with the 2 number key on the keyboard : the rectangle turns red when it is activated, and gray when it is deactivated
3. The black background turns to a red flashing background like an alarm with the 3 number key on the keyboard, the alarm stops when it is deactivated

What is the javascript code for these functions? Where should I write them? I really need help, tried to do it on my own but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance for anyone who wants to help me

Comment: Plz add the code in question and not a link to download the code!

Comment: Hi please could you put your code into the actual question - people are more likely to be able to help. See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to do this. Also explain further what you have tried and in what way it didn't work, not just that it didn't work. Thanks.